# keyboard stop working randomly

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro

I've a MBA 2009 which has a little uncommon issue :

The keyboard and the trackpad stop working randomly, sometimes just after the boot and sometimes after a few minutes. At first I thought it was a problem with the OS so I made a clean install of `10.8`, it solved the problem for an hour and then it was back.

I can affirm that it's a problem coming from thoses devices because the computer answer correctly when controlling it with `ssh`.

Furthermore, when I try to use and usb controller it doesn't work at all...

I can't run a `AHT` because the SSD have been fully erased (*before* I get the MBA)

I've isolated the corresponding log :

```
26/09/13 19:57:37,641 NotificationCenter[150]: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ffdf985d420 h=--& v=-&- H:[widgetView(385)]   (Names: widgetView:0x7ffdf8cafa30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffdf8c76330 H:|-(100)-[NSView:0x7ffdf8cb5c10](LTR)   (Names: widgetView:0x7ffdf8cafa30, '|':widgetView:0x7ffdf8cafa30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffdf8c7a110 H:[NSView:0x7ffdf8cb5c10]-(0)-|(LTR)   (Names: widgetView:0x7ffdf8cafa30, '|':widgetView:0x7ffdf8cafa30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffdf8c743d0 H:|-(0)-[NSView:0x7ffdf8cb5a40]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x7ffdf8cb5c10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffdf8c6e560 H:[NSView:0x7ffdf8cb5a40]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x7ffdf8cb5c10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffdf8cb5b40 H:[NCSwitchButton:0x7ffdf8caf5f0]-(>=9)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x7ffdf8cb5a40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffdf8cb6470 H:|-(35)-[NSTextField:0x7ffdf8cb1fa0]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x7ffdf8cb5a40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffdf8cb1af0 H:[NCSwitchButton:0x7ffdf8caf5f0(64)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffdf8cb2820 H:[NSTextField:0x7ffdf8cb1fa0]-(NSSpace(8))-[NCSwitchButton:0x7ffdf8caf5f0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffdf8cb22e0 H:[NSTextField:0x7ffdf8cb1fa0(184)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffdf8cb22e0 H:[NSTextField:0x7ffdf8cb1fa0(184)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
26/09/13 19:57:52,000 kernel[0]: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad::terminate(kIOServiceSynchronous) timeout
26/09/13 19:57:52,000 kernel[0]: USBF:  1515.994    [0xffffff8026509000] The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 6 of Hub at 0x4000000)
26/09/13 19:57:56,000 kernel[0]: USBF:  1519.  3    [0xffffff8026509000] The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
```

Second part of the log :

```
24/09/13 16:16:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0x0 returned with result 0xe0004006 - retrying
24/09/13 16:16:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0x0 returned with result 0xe0004006 - retrying
24/09/13 16:16:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReport - DeviceRequest for reportID 0x0 returned with result 0xe0004006 - retrying
24/09/13 16:16:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReport - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe0004006 (interface 0, reportID 0x0)
24/09/13 16:16:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _deviceGetReport returned an error in configurePower
```

and

```
24/09/13 16:29:31,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::validateChecksum - 54-byte packet checksum is incorrect (expected 0x98b, checksum bytes were 0x9cd)
24/09/13 16:29:31,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::validateChecksum - 54-byte packet checksum is incorrect (expected 0x973, checksum bytes were 0x926)
24/09/13 16:29:31,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::validateChecksum - 54-byte packet checksum is incorrect (expected 0x736, checksum bytes were 0x778)
24/09/13 16:29:32,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::validateChecksum - 54-byte packet checksum is incorrect (expected 0x81d, checksum bytes were 0x85f)
24/09/13 16:29:32,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::validateChecksum - 54-byte packet checksum is incorrect (expected 0xac1, checksum bytes were 0xa74)
```

The last one is repeated a lot and disabling the notification center didn't work. I'll try the EFI.

Comment: How do you know it is the keyboard and track pad? It could be your system not accepting inputs? Do you have a console log for that specific time stamp. Just 20 lines not more.

Comment: I don't have it right now but assuming that it did the same on a new system, could it be this?

Comment: It could be a application stopping the use of keyboard, or remote management, or others. The keyboard and the trackpad are independent devices, so when both stop working it is usually something stopping them. We need the log file.

Comment: Ok, I'll post it asap ;)

Comment: Not sure if it is true in your case, but I have had times when I thought keyboard and mouse was disabled... turned out I had mouse keys switching enabled.  Default behavior is to toggle mode with pressing Option keys 5 times.  Sounds like you have other issues as well though.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I've past the log ! @ Joop, unfortunately it's not coming from there...

Comment: Great, now you can see what i see in the log.

Comment: Not sure way but the trouble maker is the Notification center, i would disable it to verify : http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/06/disable-notification-center-remove-menu-bar-icon-os-x/

Comment: Now to more serious stuff the IOUSBFamily.... try resting the SMC and the EFI. If none helps try repairing your disk. Finlay you might have to reinstall the OS.

Comment: as said in the question, the installation is already a new one which have been done after constating the trouble. I've disable the notification center, wait & see... :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me too!  Same 2009 MBP on Mt Lion

I found others with same issue on forums in Dec/Jan 2013.  Fixed the issue via some command line magic words from said forums.

The problem returned and I'm so sick of mountain lion, I just use the keyboard viewer to enter text for the keys that won't work.

Believe it or not, logging out & then restarting makes the problem go away much better than simply restarting.

Comment: Terminal is very magical. :-)

Comment: Seriously, some people possess  gems of uncommonly high quality x!

Comment: You don't happen to know the Terminal command the forum mentioned? I tried to look for it but came up with no answers that were satisfactory.

Comment: unfortunately, when the keyboard stop functioning, the mouse is disabled too... But that should be great if you found thoses lines again ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reset the NVRAM or SMC yet? Firstly I would reset the PRAM and the see if that fixes your problem. If not, go on to reset SMC.

**Resetting NVRAM / PRAM**
Shut down your Mac.

1. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P,
   and R.
2. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step
   4.
3. Turn on the computer.
4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys before the gray screen appears.
5. Hold the keys down until the
   computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second
   time.
6. Release the keys.

Aft the NVRAM has been reset, you might need to setup your volume, screen brightness and some other settings again.

If this doesn't resolve your problem, I would look at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964 to reset the SMC.

Post back if either of these do not resolve your situation.

Comment: none of those two solutions worked... :(